# How many points of intersection does the graph of the irrational function $y=\sqrt{x+3}$ and the line $y=x+k$ has?

Tags: solution-verification, systems-of-equations

What are the respective values of $k$ such that there will be $2,$ only one, or no points of intersection between the graphs of the irrational function $y=\sqrt{x+3}$ and the line $y=x+k$ has?

I am not sure if my work is correct. Please feel free to share your comments and suggestions. Any comments will be appreciated.
Here is my work:

$y = \sqrt{x+3}$ , $y ≥ 0$ and $x ≥ -3$

$\sqrt{x+3} = x + k$

$x + 3 = (x + k)^2$

$x + 3 = x^2 + 2kx + k^2$

$x^2 + 2kx – x + k^2 – 3 = 0$

$x^2 + (2k – 1)x + (k^2 – 3) = 0$

$D = (2k – 1)^2 – 4(k^2 – 3)$

$D = 4k^2 – 4k + 1 – 4k^2 + 12$

$D = –4k + 13$

If the graph of the irrational function $y=\sqrt{x+3}$ and the line $y=x+k$ will intersect at two different points, then there must be two $x$ values. It follows that $D > 0$. Hence,

$D = –4k + 13 > 0$

$– 4k > – 13$

$k < \frac{13}{4}$

$x ≥ -3$

$x + k ≥ -3 + k$

$y ≥ -3 + k$ and $y ≥ 0$

$k ≥ 3$

$k ≥ 3$ and $k < \frac{13}{4}$

$3 ≤ k < \frac{13}{4}$

If the graph of the irrational function $y=\sqrt{x+3}$ and the line $y=x+k$ will intersect at exactly one point, $D = 0$. Hence,

$D = –4k + 13 = 0$

$k = \frac{13}{4}$

If the graph of the irrational function $y=\sqrt{x+3}$ and the line $y=x+k$ will not intersect, $D < 0$. Hence,
$D = –4k + 13 < 0$

$– 4k < – 13$

$k > \frac{13}{4}$.

Therefore, if $3 ≤ k < \frac{13}{4}$, the graphs will intersect at two points. If $k = \frac{13}{4}$, then the graphs will intersect at exactly one point. Lastly, if $k > \frac{13}{4}$, the graphs will not intersect.

Comment: In question it is $\sqrt{x-3}$ and in your attempt you have solved for $\sqrt{x+3}$. Also, many of the lines are repeated. Please edit your question.

Comment: @SarGe Thank you for the comment. It must be $+$ instead of $-$.

Comment: The sqrt function only takes into account the positive square root, so you have some extraneous solutions.

Comment: You forgot the case $k<3$. There is always one intersection in that case. Also, although you are correct that there are two intersections for $3\leq k < 13/4$, it's not clear to me how you derived it. What you should do is find the solutions of the equation $x+3 = (x+k)^2$ and check if $x+k \geq 0$. That's because the RHS of the original equation must be nonnegative, since the square root of a real number is nonnegative. I would advise you that you sketch graphs of the following functions: $\sqrt{x+3}$, $x+13/4$, $x+3$ and $x+k$ for any $k<3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would proceed a little bit differently from you.
First of all, we have an irrational equation with a parameter to solve, and no need to think of $y$ anymore
$$
\sqrt{x+3}=x+k.
$$
When we solve such type of equations, in which we don't know the sign of the RHS, we have to add the condition that it is non negative, so I will write
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&x+3=(x+k)^2,\\
&x+k\geq0
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Let's solve the equation, without taking into account, for the moment, the inequality. As you already found, the solutions of the equations are

1. $k<13/4$ we have two solutions
   $$
   x_{1,2}=\frac{-2k+1\mp\sqrt{13-4k}}{2};
   $$
2. $k=13/4$ we have one solution
   $$
   x_0=\frac{-2k+1}{2};
   $$
3. $k>13/4$ we have no solutions.

Next, we have to check if solutions found satisfy the other condition, the inequality $x+k\geq0.$
For the case 1. we have
$$
x_1+k=\frac{-2k+1-\sqrt{13-4k}}{2}+k\geq0\qquad\implies\qquad\sqrt{13-4k}\leq1 \\
x_2+k=\frac{-2k+1+\sqrt{13-4k}}{2}+k\geq0\qquad\implies\qquad\sqrt{13-4k}\geq-1 
$$
So, while $x_2$ is always OK, $x_1$ can be taken into account only if
$$
\sqrt{13-4k}\leq1\qquad\implies\qquad 3\leq k<\frac{13}{4}.
$$
For the case 2. we have
$$
x_0+k=\frac{-2k+1}{2}+k\geq0
$$
that is always true.

So, putting all together:

1. Two subcases:
   A. $k<3$ we have one solutions
   $$
   x_2=\frac{-2k+1+\sqrt{13-4k}}{2};
   $$
   B. $3\leq k<13/4$ we have two solutions
   $$
   x_{1,2}=\frac{-2k+1\mp\sqrt{13-4k}}{2};
   $$
2. $k=13/4$ we have one solution
   $$
   x_0=\frac{-2k+1}{2};
   $$
3. $k>13/4$ we have no solutions.

[image]

Comment: I would like to sincerely thank you for spending the time and effort to create and share your solution for my posted problem. The sequence and structure of the solution are now clear to me. Thank you so much!